# query with order by and where does not work

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to get `visit_no` using below query:

```
String strNumber = "SELECT visit_no from tracking order by id DESC limit 1 where c_no = '" + string1 + "' ";
Log.d("strNumber:", strNumber);
```

Whenever, I run above query getting *same query* in a **log**, not the actual `visit_no` because, later I need to use **same** visit_no in below *query* see `visit_no = strNumber`.

```
db.execSQL("update csv set visit_no = strNumber where c_no = '" + string1 + "' ");
```

So here is the complete method, where I have written everything

```
public void checkingRecord(String string1) {

  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

  String strNumber = "SELECT visit_no from tracking order by id DESC limit 1 where c_no = '" + string1 + "' ";
  // db.execSQL(strNumber);

  db.execSQL("update csv set visit_no = strNumber where c_no = '" + string1 + "' ");

  db.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public int checkingRecord(String string1) {
        int visit_no = 0;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT visit_no from tracking order by id DESC limit 1 where c_no = '" + string1 + "' ";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
            visit_no = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_COMPANY_ID));
            c.close();
        }

        db.close();

        return visit_no;
    }
```

After that:

```
public int updateRecord(int visit_no, String string1) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("visit_no", visit_no);

        // Which row to update, based on the ID
        String whereClause = c_no + " = ? ";
        String[] whereArgs = {String.valueOf(string1)};

        int affectedRows = db.update(
                TABLE_NAME,
                values,
                whereClause,
                whereArgs
        );

        return affectedRows;
    }
```

In your activity:

```
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(YourActivity.this);

int visit_no = databaseHelper.checkingRecord();

int update_row = databaseHelper.updateRecord(visit_no, string1);
```

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html), the WHERE clause must come *before* the ORDER BY.

And when `string1` contains a quote, everything will blow up. You should use parameters to insert strings into SQL.

And if you have two queries, you have to execute the first one, read its result, and then execute the second one.
But it is possible to do everythig at once with a subquery:

```java
String sql = "UPDATE csv "+
             "SET visit_no = (SELECT visit_no "+
                             "FROM tracking "+
                             "WHERE c_no = ? "+
                             "ORDER BY id DESC "+
                             "LIMIT 1 "+
                            ") "+
             "WHERE c_no = ?";
db.execSQL(sql, new Object[]{ string1, string1 });
```

Comment: I have tried your way, but did not get any success, issue is still there, see this link: https://pastebin.com/edZ5BsLr

Comment: That link does not show an issue, just a bunch of code.